# Custom TreeViewItem style doesn't work (is ignored)

Tags: wpf, treeview

I'm trying to modify the style of TreeViewItem, but my changes are ignored. In the following example items are added in code-behind and setting font color doesn't work.

```
<UserControl ...>
    <Grid>
        <TreeView x:Name="myTree">

            <TreeView.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Orange"/>
                </Style>
            </TreeView.Resources>

            <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        </TreeView>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

It's a part of complex project. Is it possible that some global settings override my local resources? I can't figure out what's the problem.

I note that if I set this style explicitly using x:Key value, it works for all nodes except root.

```
<TreeView.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="myStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
    ...

<TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource myStyle}" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    ...
```

Can I set my style explicitly using x:Key value for all nodes?

Comment: Its possible that there is some kind of global style being applied, although I would have thought your local one would overwrite it. You could try making your TreeViewItem style `BasedOn` any default TreeViewItem style, using `BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TreeViewItem}}"`. The only other thing I could think of is do you explicitly set the Foreground color of the `TreeViewItem` anywhere? I think if set explicitly, it will take precedence over an implicit styled value.

Comment: The reason why your template is not applied is because the template is not part of your visual tree until runtime, `WPF` applies these during compile time, So in order for you to use this `Style` for your template you need to add `x:Key` and then use it in your TreeView explicitly.

Comment: I can use style in TreeView explicitly, but I don't know how it apply to the root. If I set ItemContainerStyle of HierarchicalDataTemplate, style will be applied only for descendants and first node (root) will have default style.

Comment: @Rachel I've tried define style using BasedOn attribute, but it's still not working. I don't set Foreground explicitly. Furthermore I'm trying to apply more complex style (with triggers, bindings and converters), so it's impossible to override entire style.

Comment: @gis Can you recreate a small sample application demonstrating the problem? I tried copy/pasting your XAML into a new project and populating the TreeView with some generic items, and the implicit style seems to be working fine for me. Perhaps it would help if you shared how you are populating the TreeView, and if there is any other custom XAML.

Comment: I tried create sample project. You are right. It is working fine, but I don't understand why the same code doesn't work as part of the other project. I searched for cause of this situation, but to no effect. Finally I've set style explicitly using ItemContainerStyle property (both TreeView and HierarchicalDataTemplate) and it seems to be a solution. Thanks for helping me.